# Can someone change my app's preferences?

Tags: android, android-preferences

I want to create a preference file for my app and I want to ensure that no one will be able to change the content of the file. Can It be changed not by my app?(I change my preferences file by the code, I don't allow the user to change it with the app)

Comment: no they cant, until they know your preference name I guess!

Comment: Why don't you use SharedPreferences. That's the preferred Android way of storing settings.http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: Basically, the application preference file is saved into the application private space. So only the system or a root can access and edit it.

Comment: Use `Context.MODE_PRIVATE` while creating instance of pref.

Answer (score 1):

When you save in **shared preferences** file, it **cannot** be changed by some other user. However, if he has a **rooted** phone, it is possible for him to *view* shared preferences file, through **command-line adb root commands**, but it will be read-only so he cannot change it. If he then tries to make it read-write using

```
chmod 666
```

or similar options, it might affect your shared preferences, and the working of your app depending on *how* your app uses those shared preferences, but this will be momentarily for *that execution* and again a fresh read-only preferences file will be generated by the app. So yes, in rooted phone cases, it might be possible. But for general non-rooted cases, it cannot be done.